# Visual Studio 2013 Windows forms application not working on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi i am new to windows forms application development, I have developed an application on visual studio 2013 which is working fine on my system. Then i published it using visual studio 2013 publish option, now i am trying to run that application on other system which has windows 7 by installing it from the setup i get after publishing it. The application doesn't install and ask to download .net 4.5 framework.

How can i make an application that is compatible with windows 7 and windows xp also using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Did you download and install the .Net 4.5 framework as requested by the app? The client machines need the runtime associated with the framework you targeted.

Comment: .NET 4.5 will not install on WinXP.

Comment: how can i target older versions of .net framework in visual studio 2013?

Comment: Good article on Codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/886256/NET-versioning-and-multi-targeting-on-Csharp-appli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change [target version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , so that your application will run on Windows XP/7 .

**To change the targeted version**

1. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project that you want to change, and then choose Properties.
2. In the left column of the properties window, choose the Application tab.
3. In the Target Framework list, choose the version that you want.
4. In the verification dialog box that appears, choose the Yes button.

The project unloads. When it reloads, it targets the .NET Framework version that you just chose.

**Note:**

> After you create a Windows Store app in Visual Studio 2013, you can't
>   change the targeted version of either Windows or the .NET Framework.

Also you may use [multi targetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398197%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework 4.5 is not compatible with Win XP and previous releases of windows.You need to change the vesion of framework from your visual studio.It can be changed as follows:
File -> new project ->on the popped up window select .Net Framework 3.5 (or lesser) and create your desktop application.

One more thing is don't select "Maximize window" property for your form otherwise your form will get cropped when you run it on XP or Win7 etc.It is a general observation that I had.